# ERROR: column "student_id_list" is of type integer but expression is of type bytea

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, liquibase

I'm using liquibase changelog.xml to update my postgre database by adding a column containing arrays of student ids.  However I keep encountering this error in my logs :

```
ERROR: column "student_id_list" is of type integer but expression is of type bytea
```

I find this weird because that column should be of int array.

Here's my entity object :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_room_table")
public class ClassRoomDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "room_number", nullable = false)
    private Long roomNumber;

    @Column(name = "student_id_list")
    private int[] studentIdList;
}
```

My changelog update :

```
    <changeSet id="add-student_id_list-column-to-class_room_table" author="teacher1">
        <addColumn tableName="class_room_table">
            <column afterColumn="room_number" name="student_id_list" type="INT []"/>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
```

I'm not sure why this error is occuring since my entity holds the student id list as a int array not a bytearray.

Comment: could you try changing the type="int []" (datatype) inside the XML changeset to type="integer" and re-try?

Comment: Apparently our DB did not support this type.  So we decided to simply serialize the array and store it as a TEXT and desterilize when retrieving to store in an object.